# Can PA prove Cons(PA) under standard model?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms, provability

We know that PA cannot prove Cons(PA) without being inconsistent. But can PA prove Cons(PA') where PA' is a restricted PA that allows only the standard model (for example by defining PA' to be the common prefix of all valid models of PA or some such thing).

Comment: You are probably going to get comments asking for more details or context. An expert might easily know exactly what you are asking though. Most readers would appreciate some additional details or your own reasoning about the matter.

Comment: How do you propose to even *express* Cons(PA') in the first place? There's no first-order way to pick out the standard naturals (if there were, we wouldn't have nonstandard models in the first place).

Comment: That said, here's a cute positive result. Suppose $M\models\mathsf{PA}+\neg Cons(\mathsf{PA})$ and consider, in $M$, the smallest $n$ such that the conjunction of the first $n+1$ axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$ is inconsistent. Since $\mathsf{PA}$ proves the consistency of each of its finite subtheories and $M\models\mathsf{PA}$, $n$ must be nonstandard - so $M$ satisfies "The first $n$ axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$ form a consistent theory" and this set of "sentences" (many of which are nonstandard after all) will actually contain $\mathsf{PA}$!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Cute! That is the 'kind of trick' I was looking for. Basically the consistency of PA actually gets proved within PA. But to prove that what it proves is actually PA's own consistency, you need to use more powerful theories. Is that a reasonable way to phrase your comment?

Comment: You are mixing up models with theories. Your PA' is an **extension** of PA, not a restriction: adding axioms that disallow non-standard models is a strong step.